# Register Servlet class not found exception

Tags: jsp, servlets, jdbc

Following are servlet and web.xml files.

Register.java

```
package org.maximo.aadi;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    
response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String regno = request.getParameter("rno_input");
        String userdept = request.getParameter("userdept_input");
        String vehicletype = request.getParameter("vehicle_type_input");
        try{

        //loading drivers for mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //creating connection with the database 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vehicleRH","root","adi.12345");

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into  'vehicleRH'.'checklist'(Registeration,VehicleType,UserDept)values(regno,userdept,vehicletype");

        ps.setString(1, regno);
        ps.setString(2, userdept);
        ps.setString(3, vehicletype);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();

          if(i>0)
          {
            out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
          }

        }
        catch(Exception se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
  }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee            

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Maximo</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.maximo.aadi.Register</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

> .class file is not generating,what could be the possible error?

I am a newbie so can you tell me what is the mistake in my code?Having   trouble running the register class as it is giving error `ClassNotFound`.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you place the compiled servlet (`Register.class` file)?

Comment: src/org.maximo.aadi/Register.java

Comment: You have to compile your servlet and place the `.class` file into `WEB-INF/classes/org/maximo/aadi/` folder in your web application. I would suggest you start with a tutorial to learn the basics.

Comment: can you provide me the link for complete servlet and jdbc tutorial?....thanks in advance

Comment: Use the Force... ehm, the Google, Luke! But https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/index.html is a good start.

Comment: When asking about an exception, ALWAYS post the complete stack trace of the exception.